# error_log per Virtual Host?

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost

On one Linux Server running Apache and PHP 5, we have multiple Virtual Hosts with separate log files. We cannot seem to separate the php `error_log` between virtual hosts.

Overriding this setting in the `<Location>` of the `httpd.conf` does not seem to do anything.

Is there a way to have separate php `error_logs` for each Virtual Host?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

To set the *Apache* (*not the PHP*) log, the easiest way to do this would be to do:

```
<VirtualHost IP:Port>
   # Stuff,
   # More Stuff,
   ErrorLog /path/where/you/want/the/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

If there is no leading "/" it is assumed to be relative.

[Apache Error Log Page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#errorlog)

Comment: That's the apache error log, which is separate to the PHP error log (see other comments)

Comment: relative to what? the directory of the `httpd.conf` it's written in, or?

Answer (score 147):

If somebody comes looking it should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/example.com/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/domains/example.com/apache.error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/domains/example.com/apache.access.log common
    php_flag log_errors on
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 2147483647
    php_value error_log /var/www/domains/example.com/php.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

This is for *development only* since `display_error` is turned on. You will notice that the Apache error log is separate from the PHP error log. The good stuff is in `php.error.log`.

Take a look here for the `error_reporting` key http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Comment: Depending on your config, you may need to manually create the log file and set the owner/group to the same user/group that Apache is using. Apache won't warn you if it can't write to the log file.

Comment: Note that the "error_reporting" value changes with new versions of PHP as they add more error levels. E_ALL = "30719" right now.

Comment: Since "error_reporting" values keep changing and since you can't use PHP constants like "E_ALL" and "E_STRICT" outside of php, this is how you ensure you always have ALL errors logged: php_value error_reporting 2147483647

Comment: Why would you want your log in your public domain space?

Comment: The log file wouldn't be public. /html/ is the public space.

Answer (score 15):

I usually just specify this in an `.htaccess` file *or* the `vhost.conf` on the domain I'm working on. Add this to one of these files:

```
php_admin_value error_log "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/error_log"
```

Comment: Can anyone comment on the difference between `php_admin_value` and `php_value`?

Comment: This explains the difference: http://mattiasgeniar.be/2012/02/18/php-php_value-vs-php_admin_value-and-the-use-of-php_flag-explained/

Comment: @Jeremy That page no longer exists. Sorry. this post is really old.

Comment: @tmarois Updated link: https://ma.ttias.be/php-php_value-vs-php_admin_value-and-the-use-of-php_flag-explained/

Answer (score 9):

The default behaviour for error_log() is to output to the Apache error log. If this isn't happening check your php.ini settings for the error_log directive. Leave it unset to use the Apache log file for the current vhost.

Comment: I will check. I just wonder if it is possible to still have apache and php error log separate when we want to give developers a chance to debug their code without giving them the apache error log which might contain other sensitive data.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the `php_value error_log '/path/to/php_error_log` to your VirtualHost configuration.

Answer (score 7):

Don't set `error_log` to where your `syslog` stuff goes, `eg /var/log/apache2`, because they errors will get intercepted by `ErrorLog`. Instead, create a `subdir` in your *project folder* for logs and do `php_value` `error_log "/path/to/project/logs"`. This goes for both `.htaccess` *files and vhosts*. Also make sure you put `php_flag` `log_errors` on

Comment: Interesting. Does this behavior depend on the path of the error_log file?

Answer (score 6):

```
php_value error_log "/var/log/httpd/vhost_php_error_log"
```

It works for me, but I have to change the permission of the log file.

or Apache will write the log to the its `error_log`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can try,

```
php_value error_log "/var/log/php_log"
```

in `.htaccess` or you can have users use `ini_set()` in the beginning of their scripts if they want to have logging.

Another option would be to enable scripts to default to the `php.ini` in the folder with the script, then go to the user/host's root folder, then to the server's root, or something similar. This would allow hosts to add their own `php.ini` values and their own `error_log` locations.

Answer (score 4):

My Apache had something like this in httpd.conf. Just change the ErrorLog and CustomLog settings

```
<VirtualHost myvhost:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/web
    ServerName myvhost
    ErrorLog logs/myvhost-error_log
    CustomLog logs/myvhost-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: We're talking about the PHP log, not the Apache log here.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
    <VirtualHost myvhost:80>
       php_value error_log "/var/log/httpd/vhost_php_error_log"
    </Virtual Host>
```

But I'm not sure if it is going to work. I tried on my sites with no success.

Answer (score 2):

Create Simple VirtualHost:

example hostname:- `thecontrolist.localhost`

1. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

   `127.0.0.1 thecontrolist.localhost`    in hosts file
2. C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

   ```
   <VirtualHost *>
     ServerName thecontrolist.localhost
     ServerAlias thecontrolist.localhost
     DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs/thecontrolist"
     <Directory "/xampp/htdocs/thecontrolist">
       Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require local
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Don't Forget to restart Your apache. 
   for more [check](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ExampleVhosts) this link