# no php error logging on apache

Tags: php, apache2

Seems like I can't get error logging working on my server, I've set up my vhosts like in this description [like suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176/apache-php-error-log-per-virtual-host).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@server.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   ServerName www.server.com
   ServerAlias server.com
   LogFormat combined
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/server.com-error_log
   TransferLog /var/log/apache2/server.com-access_log
   php_flag log_errors on
   php_flag display_errors off
   php_value error_reporting 6143
   php_value error_log /var/log/apache2/server.com-php-error.log
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

access and error log are written correctly, the php error log file is created and has the same permission as the other two log files.

I also tried to set the logging in the php.ini, .htaccess file and in the script, all according to [this guide](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/log-php-errors-log-errors-error-log/).

```
php -v
 PHP 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.10 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.7 (cli) (built: May  2 2011 23:24:44) 
 Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
 Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

Are there any other places I could check? The vHost configuration worked flawlessly on other servers.

Comment: What is your question? You say the log is created and everything, it would have the same permissions since it is created by the same user in the log dir. What is actually wrong? And what are you trying to check?

Comment: so have you tried accessing a page with a PHP error on it?

Comment: the error-log and access-log are created but not the server.com-php-error.log, nothing gets written into that file.

Comment: As @dnagirl says have you done anything that requests a log to be written?

Comment: yes I've a page with an error, also it should log any `error_log()` in that file too?

Comment: I think this is something isolated to your server rather than the config code you have displayed here

Comment: Make sure that those php_value values aren't being overridden somewhere farther down the httpd.conf chain - there can be many other .conf-type files included later on. If your settings, as shown above, were in effect, they'd show in `phpinfo()` output. Check that to see what's really in effect.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's due to permissions on `/var/log/apache2`. Take into account that PHP is running as an apache module, so it is running as the `www-data` user (in ubuntu at least). So you need that this user has at least execute permission on `/var/log/apache2` and write permission on the log files, or better yet, execute and write permission on `/var/log/apache2` (to be able to create new log files if needed).

So you can save the php log to another folder, or make it writable by the `www-data` user (in the latter case, you may also edit the `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` file so new logfiles after rotation get owned by the `www-data` user.

Comment: As you say, the log is written with Apache's permissions - if it was a permission error, then apache wouldn't be able to open its own standard logs and kill itself with a startup fatal error.

Comment: @MarcB you're wrong, because apache starts as the `root` user, logs the requests to that folder and then it downgrades privileges to the `www-data` user.

Comment: Yes, but the php module will also be running as root at the time the log files are opened. the relinquishing of root privs is only done AFTER all startup activities are finished.

Comment: @MarcB but the php logger does not log the requests, it does log the error, which happen after the downgrading of privileges, because the php parser/interpreter is not run as root

Comment: so? the php module stays alive within Apache for the lifetime of Apache, and keeps the error log open, even after the privs drop. The log is not continually opened/written/closed every time.

Comment: Apache apparently has the permissions to write in that folder because the access and normal error log are working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Type into your php script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Than you get your errors and warnings printed

Comment: displaying errors in the browser works but that doesn't help debugging backend php. I think everyone would agree that there should be a log file, displaying in the browser is only a temporary solution.

Comment: For debugging in development okay, in production is this a bad solution right. /etc/log/httpd/error_log could help maybe

Answer (score 0):

Try the default location for PHP log: /var/log/php.log

Comment: There is no log in the default location