# php not logging errors log_errors=on, error_log path exists

Tags: php, apache

Using php5.6 (legacy codebase), apache, ubuntu16.

`phpinfo()` says that:
`log_errors` is on
`error_log` = `/var/log/apache2/php_errors.log`

When `display_errors` is on there is output.
But `/var/log/apache2/` does not contain a `php_errors.log` file.

Have restarted apache (`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`).

`log_errors_max_len` is `1024`.

```
ls -ld /var/log/apache2
drwxr-x--- 2 root   adm    4096 Mar 30 18:47 apache2

ls -l /var/log/apache2
-rw-r----- 1 root adm        0 Mar 30 06:25 access.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm     5967 Mar 30 01:47 access.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root adm    11618 Mar 31 04:07 error.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm    11742 Mar 30 06:25 error.log.1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Apache2? If so, your virtual host(s) might specify other log file locations where PHP errors/warnings/etc. are output. Check `/var/log/apache2/*-error.log`

Comment: You are correct! Is there a directive I can add to separate out the php error log?

Comment: try `error_log=syslog` and if it works then it is a write permission issue

Comment: In fact, `phpinfo()` should display *two* values ("Local value" and "Master value") and whenever different the first one is the one in effect. You also probably need to run PHP as Apache module in order to be able to log into `/var/log/apache`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From above comments. When using Apache2, each VirtualHost can have it's own log files.

So the `/etc/apache2/` directory would have a `sites-available` directory along these lines:

```
├── sites-available
│   ├── 000-default.conf
│   ├── default-ssl.conf
│   ├── default-tls.conf
│   ├── www.domain.com.conf
│   └── www.domain.com-le-ssl.conf
```

And the `www.` files might look like the following example.

To set up specific php log file, separate from Apache logs, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3576664/2223106):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/example.com/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/domains/example.com/apache.error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/domains/example.com/apache.access.log common
    php_flag log_errors on
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 2147483647
    php_value error_log /var/www/domains/example.com/php.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```