# How do you set the PHP error log location in the Apache configuration file?

Tags: php, apache, config

We have an out-of-the-box PHP application running on a subdomain, and it's logging errors in its DocumentRoot:

```
/var/www/appname/path/to/document/root/php-errors.log
```

...instead of where we want the error logs to go:

```
/var/www/appname/logs/php-errors.log
```

Since I don't want to change the code in the out-of-the-box application, and I don't want to change the error log location for *all* the subdomains (read: file *php.ini*), how can I do this in just the Apache configuration file that relates to the subdomain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From *[error_log per Virtual Host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176/error-log-per-virtual-host#3576664)*:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/example.com/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/domains/example.com/apache.error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/domains/example.com/apache.access.log common
    php_flag log_errors on
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 2147483647
    php_value error_log /var/www/domains/example.com/php.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it's dead right, but I got my question wrong - I need it for PHP run as FastCGI. I'll pop a new question up for that one

Comment: See if this helps: https://serverfault.com/questions/763719/setting-php-value-in-virtualhost-on-debian-squeeze-apache-2-4-10-mod-proxy-fcg#773813

Comment: I'd reply here with how to do it in FPM to keep the trail, but I'll post a new answer because it's a bit tricky and has a few steps. Thanks for the answer and comment response @mkaatman, you're a life saver

Comment: I thought it was better to indicate that `php_value` won't work for PHP-FPM because Apache did not load the libphp module

Answer (score 8):

For those wishing to do this using php-fpm (which I meant to originally post about), here's how you do it:

Ensure you're logged in as root, or using `sudo` for all your commands.

Go into your php-fpm directory*, using the command below:

```
cd /etc/php/fpm/
```

In that directory, edit your php.ini file and add the following to the end:

**If you want to set error log by host**

```
[HOST=www.example.com]
error_log=/var/www/myapplication/path/to/my/error.log

[HOST=sub.example.com]
error_log=/var/www/mysubapplication/path/to/my/error.log
```

**If you want to set error log by path**
(handy if you're working on a server with an IP address but no domain)

```
[PATH=/var/www/myapplication]
error_log=/var/www/myapplication/path/to/my/error.log

[PATH=/var/www/mysubapplication]
error_log=/var/www/mysubapplication/path/to/my/error.log
```

You now need to go into the pool directory*, using the command below:

```
cd /etc/php/fpm/pool.d/
```

In that directory, edit the file www.conf. Note the values for `user` and `group` in that file, whose out-of-the-box setting is `www-data` for both. Look for the term `catch_workers_output` and make sure it is uncommented and set to `yes`, like so:

```
catch_workers_output = yes
```

Now you need to create the error log file(s) and ensure that php-fpm has access to it. This is why you needed to note the values for `user` and `group` from the previous file edit. Create an error log file for each HOST/PATH you set when editing `php.ini` and give them the appropriate permissions and ownership, for example:

```
touch /var/www/myapplication/path/to/my/error.log
chmod 0660 /var/www/myapplication/path/to/my/error.log
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/myapplication/path/to/my/error.log
```

Finally, restart your php-fpm service using the command** below:

```
service php-fpm restart
```

---

* *Note: If, like me, you install declared versions of php-fpm, the directory paths will change to (for example) the following:*

```
/etc/php/5.6/fpm/
/etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/

/etc/php/7.1/fpm/
/etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/
```

** *The service takes a specific versioned name if you installed declared versions, and you will need use (for example) the following:*

```
service php5.6-fpm restart

service php7.1-fpm restart
```

Comment: A side-note, I find it is easier to manage/automate when you add the logs to the `/etc/php-fpm.d` location. I do something like: `999-php-logs-example.com.conf` Then I add something like: 
`[PATH=/var/www/vhosts/example.com]error_log=/var/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/php-error.log slowlog=/var/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/php-slow.log`.... sorry, cannot add multi-line code block

Answer (score 2):

I configure it like this:

#### File */etc/apache2/envvars*

```
# For supporting multiple Apache 2 instances
if [ "${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}" != "${APACHE_CONFDIR}" ] ; then
    SUFFIX="-${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}"
else
    SUFFIX=
fi
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX
```

#### File */etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf*

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```